# How to incorporate grape flavor in a chiffon cake?

Tags: baking, cake, batter

I'm trying to make a layer of chiffon cake, with a grape flavor but I'm not satisfied with the flavor. I have tried using the juice from the grapes, incorporated into the batter, but it is not particularly potent and the end result is rather bland for my palate.

What would be the best way to incorporate a grape flavor? Is there anything I can do to the grapes to enhance the flavor and maybe add more depth or complexity?

Comment: [Grape Extract](https://www.amazon.com/Lorann-Oils-Grape-Ounce-Flavoring/dp/B000Q3L7R6/ref=sr_1_3_s_it?s=grocery&ie=UTF8&qid=1528154488&sr=1-3&keywords=grape+extract) as used in candy making seems like a good bet.

Comment: It's really going to depend on the *kind* of grape flavor you're looking for... are you looking for the "candy" grape flavor or the more subtle grape flavor from actual grapes such as white grapes?

Comment: @GdD please post such info as an answer or not at all, comments are not a suitable place for it.

Answer (score 2):

Grape juice, purchased as such, is often diluted with water and sugar and other juices. Additionally, many varieties of grapes, especially table grapes, don't have very much flavor at all.

Using grape juice concentrate will add a ton of sugar which you might be able to compensate for in the recipe. Unfortunately, in a chiffon cake, the sugar plays a role in stabilizing the egg foam.

Fresh, undiluted, unsweetened, Concord grape juice has a lot of flavor and color and is not overly sweet. I don't know where one can acquire it as I get it from neighbors who grow it. Perhaps homebrew supply store might have some for small wine batches.

Failing that, grape extract could most easily be used, as renisis commented above, but the flavor will be less fruity and simpler- like grape candy.

Comment: hey sobachatina, nice to see you again on the site! Good answer, as always.

Comment: In the US, Welch's sells 100% Concord grape juice, shelf stable concentrate, and frozen concentrate. They also sell 100% red grape juice and 100% white grape juice. Should be quite easy to find. These are all 100% juice, unlike grape juice drinks or grape juice cocktail.

Comment: Odd. It seems sweeter than when I get juicing grapes myself. Maybe it's a sweeter variety or I'm selectively remembering things.